# How to make Sencha Cmd 5 generate php file?

Tags: sencha-cmd

I have in my ExtJS app index.php , I've changed declared in app.json :

```
 "indexHtmlPath": "index.php",
```

but when I build the app using sencha cmd I always get index.html (with the content of the php file).

How do I force the file to be named index.php once the command finish ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at these:

- http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?255122-Rename-index.html-to-index.php
- http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?275806-Change-from-index.html-to-index.php

Let me know if it still doesn't work.